# split a six digits number column into separated columns with one digit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

how can I by using pandas or numpy separate one column of 6 integer digits into 6 columns with one digit each?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series(range(123456,123465))

df = pd.DataFrame(df)


df.head()
```

#### what I have is like this one below

```
Number
654321
223344
```

#### The desired outcome should be like this one below.

```
Number | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 |
654321 |  6 |  5 | 4  |  3 |  2 |  1 |
223344 |  2 |  2 | 3  |  3 |  4 |  4 |
```

Comment: If you don't have to use numpy or pandas - `for num in str(my_number): print(num)`

Comment: What is *source* of your data? `numpy.array` or `pandas.dataframe` are delivered to you or you are getting just text with numbers separated by newlines?

Comment: How on earth is this "too broad"? This is easily in the top 10% of most specific and clear questions on this site.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I just realize it has been flagged to broad, I do not understand, seems clear to me. May be it lacks a better description of input and desired types for output.

Answer (score 8):

#### MCVE

Here is a simple suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd

# MCVE dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame([123456, 456789, 135797, 123, 123456789], columns=['number'])

def digit(x, n):
    """Return the n-th digit of integer in base 10"""
    return (x // 10**n) % 10

def digitize(df, key, n):
    """Extract n less significant digits from an integer in base 10"""
    for i in range(n):
        df['x%d' % i] = digit(df[key], n-i-1)

# Apply function on dataframe (inplace):
digitize(df, 'number', 6)
```

For the trial dataframe, it returns:

```
      number  x0  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
0     123456   1   2   3   4   5   6
1     456789   4   5   6   7   8   9
2     135797   1   3   5   7   9   7
3        123   0   0   0   1   2   3
4  123456789   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

#### Observations

This method avoids the need to cast into `string` and then cast again to `int`.

It relies on modular integer arithmetic, bellow details of operations:

```
10**3                  # int: 1000 (integer power)
54321 // 10**3         # int: 54   (quotient of integer division)
(54321 // 10**3) % 10  # int: 4    (remainder of integer division, modulo)
```

Last but not least, it is fail safe and exact for number shorter than `n` digits or greater than (notice it returns the `n` less significant digits in latter case).

Comment: get rid off `apply`, you can simply do `digit(df['Number'], i)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you for pointing this out, is there any benefit (performance) alongside with code compactness and readability?

Comment: Without apply, it's vectorized, so you would see big improvement in terms of speed.

Answer (score 4):

Some fun with views, assuming that each number has 6 digits:

---

```
u = df[['Number']].to_numpy().astype('U6').view('U1').astype(int)

df.join(pd.DataFrame(u).rename(columns=lambda c: f'x{c+1}'))
```

```
   Number  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
0  654321   6   5   4   3   2   1
1  223344   2   2   3   3   4   4
```

Comment: Impressive one-liner, although it breaks if there are numbers with different number of digits.

Comment: Yea, that assumption has to be made, definitely more of a trick than something to use.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `np.unravel_index`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [654321,223344]})

def split_digits(df):
    # get data as numpy array
    numbers = df['Number'].to_numpy()
    # extract digits
    digits = np.unravel_index(numbers, 6*(10,))
    # create column headers
    columns = ['Number', *(f'x{i}' for i in "123456")]
    # build and return new data frame
    return pd.DataFrame(np.stack([numbers, *digits], axis=1), columns=columns, index=df.index)


split_digits(df)
#    Number  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
# 0  654321   6   5   4   3   2   1
# 1  223344   2   2   3   3   4   4

timeit(lambda:split_digits(df),number=1000)
# 0.3550272472202778
```

Thanks @GZ0 for some `pandas` tips.

Comment: This is an excellent trick and one-lines @Paul +1, What does `**` in `assign`, would you mind explaining the code.

Comment: @KarnKumar `**` "unrolls" the dictionary, so each key-value pair becomes a keyword argument to the function (`assign` in this case). Btw. I don't know much about `pandas`, so this part of the code may be far from being optimal.

Comment: @KarnKumar I've made an annotated version in case you are interested.

Comment: One alternative way to return a new data frame using `digits` is `df.assign(**dict(zip((f'x{i}' for i in range(1,7)), digits)))`. Also, `df['Number']` can be used as a numpy array directly without explicitly accessing the `.values` attribute.

Comment: @GZ0 funny, I had used more or less the `assign` idiom you suggest before editing. But it seemed quite slow compared to what I settled for. I don't know whether pandas does something stupid like adding the new columns one by one or something. Anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: @PaulPanzer You solution is indeed a lot more performant. `df.assign` makes a copy of the orignal dataframe and then add columns one by one. The `df.copy()` call actually takes a lot more time than adding columns for some unknown reasons. IMO there are two things that could be improved in your solution though: (1) In `pandas` version >= 0.24.0, `df.to_numpy()` is recommended in favor of `df.values`; (2) the index of the original data frame should be preserved by passing `index=df.index` into the constructor function.

Comment: @GZ0 Updated. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulPanzer, thanks for placing annotation it helps other to better understand a new trick :-)

Answer (score 3):

#### Turn it into a string first!

Also, included a `zfill` just in case not all numbers are 6 digits

```
dat = [list(map(int, str(x).zfill(6))) for x in df.Number]
d = pd.DataFrame(dat, df.index).rename(columns=lambda x: f'x{x + 1}')
df.join(d)

   Number  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
0  654321   6   5   4   3   2   1
1  223344   2   2   3   3   4   4
```

---

#### Details

This gets the digits

```
dat = [list(map(int, str(x).zfill(6))) for x in df.Number]
dat

[[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], [2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]]
```

This creates a new dataframe with the same index as `df` **AND** renames the columns to have an `'x'` in front and begin with `'x1'` and not `'x0'`

```
d = pd.DataFrame(dat, df.index).rename(columns=lambda x: f'x{x + 1}')
d

   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
0   6   5   4   3   2   1
1   2   2   3   3   4   4
```

Answer (score 3):

While string-based solutions are simpler and probably good enough in most cases, you can do this with math which, if you have a big data set, can make a significant difference in speed.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Number': [654321, 223344]})
num_cols = int(np.log10(df['Number'].max() - 1)) + 1
vals = (df['Number'].values[:, np.newaxis] // (10 ** np.arange(num_cols - 1, -1, -1))) % 10
df_digits = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=[f'x{i + 1}' for i in range(num_cols)
df2 = pd.concat([df, df_digits])], axis=1)
print(df2)
#    Number  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
# 0  654321   6   5   4   3   2   1
# 1  223344   2   2   3   3   4   4
```

Comment: I definitely like this approach.  I'm trying to make this prettier (-:

Comment: `vals = (df.to_numpy() // 10 ** np.arange(6) % 10)[:, ::-1]`  Obviously, assumptions have to be made.  I basically made some golf improvements at the expense of generalization.

Answer (score 1):

I really liked @user3483203's answer. I think `.str.findall` could work with any number of digits:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Number' : [65432178888, 22334474343]
})

u = df['Number'].astype(str).str.findall(r'(\w)')
df.join(pd.DataFrame(list(u)).rename(columns=lambda c: f'x{c+1}')).apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

```py
        Number x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11
0  65432178888  6  5  4  3  2  1  7  8  8   8   8
1  22334474343  2  2  3  3  4  4  7  4  3   4   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all numbers are of same length (have equal number of digits), I would do it following way using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[654321],[223344]])
str_a = a.astype(str)
out = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:list(x[0]),1,str_a)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[['6' '5' '4' '3' '2' '1']
 ['2' '2' '3' '3' '4' '4']]
```

Note that `out` is currently `np.array` of `str`s, you might convert it to `int` if such need arise.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way around:

```
>>> df
   number
0  123456
1  456789
2  135797
```

First convert the column into string

```
>>> df['number'] = df['number'].astype(str)
```

Create the new columns using string indexing

```
>>> df['x1'] = df['number'].str[0]
>>> df['x2'] = df['number'].str[1]
>>> df['x3'] = df['number'].str[2]
>>> df['x4'] = df['number'].str[3]
>>> df['x5'] = df['number'].str[4]
>>> df['x6'] = df['number'].str[5]

>>> df
   number x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
0  123456  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  456789  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  135797  1  3  5  7  9  7

>>> df.drop('number', axis=1, inplace=True)
>>> df
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  1  3  5  7  9  7
```

@another trick with `str.split()`

```
>>> df = df['number'].str.split('(\d{1})', expand=True).add_prefix('x').drop(columns=['x0',  'x2', 'x4', 'x6', 'x8', 'x10', 'x12'])
>>> df
  x1 x3 x5 x7 x9 x11
0  1  2  3  4  5   6
1  4  5  6  7  8   9
2  1  3  5  7  9   7

>>> df.rename(columns={'x3':'x2',  'x5':'x3',  'x7':'x4', 'x9':'x5', 'x11':'x6'})
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  1  3  5  7  9  7
```

### OR

```
>>> df  = df['number'].str.split(r'(\d{1})', expand=True).T.replace('', np.nan).dropna().T

>>> df
  1  3  5  7  9  11
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  1  3  5  7  9  7

>>> df.rename(columns={1:'x1', 3:'x2', 5:'x3', 7:'x4', 9:'x5', 11:'x6'})
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
0  1  2  3  4  5  6
1  4  5  6  7  8  9
2  1  3  5  7  9  7
```